# INSERT / UPDATE SQL random & unique VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, random, insert, unique, varchar

I need to be able to `INSERT/UPDATE UNIQUE RANDOM UTF8 ALPHANUMERICAL VARCHAR 55` into a table field called 'key'.

Can't find out any good query example, does anyone can show me or link me something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on mysql.

This select will create 55 char long random strings:

```
select substr(concat(md5(rand()),md5(rand())),1,55);
```

to fill your table column you might want to try out:

```
create table example (keycol varchar(55));
```

**insert into example (keycol) values (substr(concat(md5(rand()),md5(rand())),1,55));**

The result will be:

```
select keycol from example;

+---------------------------------------------------------+
| keycol                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 4517f4be669301a4a529b53fc18d646dec42d4d07d911d33a67c863 | 
| 3caa1c98f0f9ee39515aa6f4ddb3f84fa41abd5392f610c5d24bcd9 | 
| 8e52cb4ce29e58514671c9b68f19832f26ddf53f277621ac420bd2e | 
| 3adcccfb6cb729ce1c0a14fb75f6fd54f58992dc0751527c969e007 | 
| c28c5879589dc90f4fb0963673e5668fa5789d325423ba043e0243b | 
| 8f7a2af97d73261008f0d0d7249480fde56a3a91f2ce6e8bf0b0070 | 
| ff4f74f25b92da3eaab282218c23a75d4cfa77c8f8bfdf74d7ebdf9 | 
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can't understand ... you showed me a select why i need an insert and an update! So if i use the insert you showed with field UNIQUE is it ok? then how to update that field?

Comment: if you can show me the UPDATE query too .. this goona be the right answer!

Comment: or i will got problems with that in future when fields will be many many?

Comment: a 55 char random md55 like this is practically impossible to repeate by chance even if you used all the computers of the world to try at the same time. Make sure the randomize is done before you use random ...
The update issue would mean you'd exchange the key update(... set key="..." where key="oldkey" ...